# Does North Korea's aircraft registration prefix allow for only 500 aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-registration

In the Wikipedia page [about aircraft registration prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_registration_prefixes), we can see that North Korea has P-500 to P-999. Does that mean that it’s only allowed 500 planes? What happens when the registry is all used?

(Oddly enough, I visited that Wikipedia page after reading an article about Star Trek’s starship Enterprise, also on Wikipedia.)

Comment: This is for civil, not military, aircraft registration, so 500 might actually be plenty for North Korea.

Comment: Even if they don't have that many, I'm not sure DPRK would follow an international designation from an organization they aren't a part of.

Comment: @RonBeyer They’re a member of both ITU and ICAO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Civil aircraft tail numbers almost always follow ITU radio prefixes. North Korea has been allocated six ITU prefixes: HM and P5-P9.

Many countries with consecutive 2-letter prefixes will move the dash so it looks like they have a 1-letter prefix, but they still only use the allowed subset. So in this case, rather than P5-00 to P9-99, they write P-500 to P-999. They could have just as easily chosen P-50000 to P-99999 if they wanted, or gone alphabetic for even more possibilities.

However, in practice North Korea only has a handful of very old civil aircraft. While there is a humanitarian exception for spare parts to keep their airlines safe, the country can’t buy any *more* planes, which means they don’t *need* more tail numbers than they’re currently using. Heck, they could probably knock off a digit and *still* have more than they need!